# Comparing cell to various other cells and returning the number of found and not found

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Ok, I know this is hard that even me struggling to understand and put a formula for this but let me explain.

-I have a sheet that has some cells full of tags for agents and others for QA.

-I want to compare the tags the agents have used against the tags of what the QA has used and which will be counted as a mistake.

-So I want to return the number of the matches between agent and QA as per the screenshot

[image]

Here is the sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CijQocy96sWpFID2i1BJBkTnTieOyLjP25Ve7KzAc_E/edit#gid=0

Your help is very appreciated <3

Comment: Missing screenshot?

Comment: Hi i updated it, its in the sheet also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In L2 I entered

```
=counta(A2:D2) - sumproduct(isnumber(match(A2:D2, F2:I2, 0)))
```

and filled down.

A variation of the above formula can be found in N2 (and down).

See if that helps?

Comment: omg its magic and easier than i thought. i thought about using regmatch but it failed so bad. thank you so much till the moon JPV, you saved my day <3 :)

Comment: can i ask you how the formula accepted " - " after you put the counta formula??? this is very new to me.

Comment: Most welcome, @RedaElbarbary. Glad to hear I was able to help. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if this solved your issue.

Comment: Basically you count the non-empty cells and subtract the number of matches found.

Comment: oh my, that's so intelligent JPV. have an awesome life.

Comment: can we find out whats the differences from the QA perspective, please?

Comment: @Redz85: Can you explain what you mean? Better yet, show the expected outcome of what it is you want to achieve?