# Comparing cell to other and returning the difference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I had an issue before returning the number of differences between 2 sections of cells as mentioned here: [Comparing cell to various other cells and returning the number of found and not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906749/comparing-cell-to-various-other-cells-and-returning-the-number-of-found-and-not/67907859?noredirect=1#comment120029244_67907859)

Now my issue is that I want a formula to search the columns from QA in Agent and return the differences and ignore the matches

[image]

So here in the first row, there are 2 differences in the QA column comparing to the agent, i want to return those 2 differences from that.

Link of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CijQocy96sWpFID2i1BJBkTnTieOyLjP25Ve7KzAc_E/edit#gid=0

Your help is highly appreciated <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your request correctly, but see if this helps ?

```
=iferror(join(", ", filter(F2:J2, len(F2:J2), not(isnumber(match(F2:J2, A2:E2, 0))))))
```

or

```
=iferror(join(", ", query(transpose(F2:J2), "where Col1 <>'' and not(Col1) matches '"&textjoin("|", 1,A2:E2)&"'", 0)))
```

Also see cells P2 and 02 (and down) in the spreadsheet you shared. If that is not what you wanted to achieve, please show the expected output.

Comment: Exactly JPV, that was excellent. just one thing, I want the results to be separated into cells cuz I want to analyze the outcome into charts. can you please help me with this :)

Comment: In that case, leave out the join() function: =iferror(filter(F2:J2, len(F2:J2), not(isnumber(match(F2:J2, A2:E2, 0)))))